# Trying to build first Spring project with maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am trying to build my first Spring project with maven it was working before using maven but now that I am trying to do the build with maven I am getting the following output. can someonme please tell me whats wround

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building WebFlowTemplate Maven Webapp
[INFO]    task-segment: [package]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to /home/jsmith/Downloads/home/jsmith/Documents/workspace-sts-3.0.0/WebFlowTemplate/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure

/home/jsmith/Downloads/home/jsmith/Documents/workspace-sts-3.0.0/WebFlowTemplate/src/main/java/org/uftwf/webflowtemplate/service/TestServiceImpl.java:[9,1] annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
@Service

/home/jsmith/Downloads/home/jsmith/Documents/workspace-sts-3.0.0/WebFlowTemplate/src/main/java/org/uftwf/webflowtemplate/controller/HelloWorldController.java:[8,1] annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
@Controller

/home/jsmith/Downloads/home/jsmith/Documents/workspace-sts-3.0.0/WebFlowTemplate/src/main/java/org/uftwf/webflowtemplate/controller/swf/HellowWorldFlowActions.java:[3,7] static import declarations are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable static import declarations)
import static org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger;

/home/jsmith/Downloads/home/jsmith/Documents/workspace-sts-3.0.0/WebFlowTemplate/src/main/java/org/uftwf/webflowtemplate/controller/swf/HellowWorldFlowActions.java:[13,1] annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
@Component

/home/jsmith/Downloads/home/jsmith/Documents/workspace-sts-3.0.0/WebFlowTemplate/src/main/java/org/uftwf/webflowtemplate/domain/Customer.java:[7,1] annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
@SuppressWarnings("serial")


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Sep 13 22:09:00 EDT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/163M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

this is my pox.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springsource.greenbeans.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebFlowTemplate</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>WebFlowTemplate Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
<!-- 
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-server-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>

-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-cas-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core-tiger</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

<!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-ext</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-server-jndi</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>WebFlowTemplate</finalName>

    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are working with JDK version prior to 1.5. Annotation support in java has been introduced since JDK 1.5 and you should configure your project to be run with 1.5 or higher as follows:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```